# wso2 esb mediator is singleton

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I configure two proxies in ESB, and these 2 proxies are bridged to one instance mediator. And I have different property set for mediator in proxy configuration. 
I expect that the two mediators instances are running in ESB with different properties. 
But in fact, seems only mediator instance is in ESB.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Please post your proxy service configuration to give additional insight into the problem. Also: which mediator are you using? Is it one of those shipped with the ESB or is it a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake here. In java code, spring bean is used to contain mediator property configured in xml file. But spring bean is singleton and causes different configuration cannot be applied in different proxy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="abc"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable"
       statistics="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="address"
                 scope="transport"
                  expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('To'),'/services/crownperth')"/>
         <class name="com.abc.customerintegration.mediator.CustomerInfoMediator">
          <property name="pmServerAddress" value="http://192.168.112.243:3509/MobileConnectService"></property>
           <property name="property" value="P"/>
          <property name="languageCode" value="en-US"></property>
         </class>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="def"
       transports="http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable"
       statistics="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="address"
                 scope="transport"
                  expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('To'),'/services/crownperth')"/>
         <class name="com.abc.customerintegration.mediator.CustomerInfoMediator">
          <property name="pmServerAddress" value="http://192.168.112.243:3509/MobileConnectService"></property>
           <property name="property" value="P"/>
          <property name="languageCode" value="en-US"></property>
         </class>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```